# PyMysql-Python:How to check if an input a user gives exists in my database

Tags: python, pymysql

I have a table like this:

```
Movies:
Title    Rank
a        5
b        6
b        6.5
c        7
```

lets say thats my table.I want to find if an input(title of a movie) a user gives from his keyboard exists in my database and if the movie that he selected exists only once in the table.

Comment: Are you able to establish connection to the database ?

Comment: yeah i have done all that.

Comment: Is your output into dataframe ?

Comment: my problem is I dont know how to relate an sql query with the input...I dont know how to write it correctly.

Comment: for example I want as an asnwer something like this:

Comment: cursor.executr("select movie.title from movie where movie.title=input",(item_name))

Comment: Yeah, check my answer, you might relate now

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check with `sql query`

```
>>> user_input = input('Enter movie title: ')
>>> sql_query = 'select title from movie where title = {}'.format(user_input)
>>> cursor.execute(sql_query)
>>> result = cursor.fetchone()
>>> row = result[0]
```

Or if your query result is in dataframe:

```
>>> user_input in df['Title'].tolist()
```

Comment: if i want to check the number of affected rows so i can know if its one movie that has been selected or more i do this?

Comment: cursor.execute("select title from movie where title = {}'.format(user_input)",(lineitem))  row_count = cursor.rowcount